# How to fix the electron app window size in different display resolution

Tags: html, angular, typescript, electron

My laptop resolution: 1920 x 1080

1st monitor: 3840 x 1260

2nd monitor: 2560 x 1440

I created an login app in electron. I set the size for the app

In index.html

```
body {
  width: 453px;
  height: 518px;
  resize: none;
}
```

in style.css

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 453px;
  height: 518px;
  resize: none;
}
```

In Main.ts

```
function createMainWindow(): BrowserWindow {

  win = new BrowserWindow({
width: 452,
height: 518,
center: true,
frame: false,
show: false,
fullscreenable: false,
resizable: false,
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: true,
  plugins: true,
  allowRunningInsecureContent: true,
  webSecurity: false,
  contextIsolation: false,
  devTools: isDev()
},
});
```

the part of UI in laptop resolution, it looks good.

[image]

When I moved the app to the 2nd monitor, the app looks like this: the width and height will be extended, but the original app size is still correct. Just the app window is larger than normal size.

[image]

Any way to prevent the size like that when drag the app to different display resolution?

Comment: Have you tried setting `zoomFactor: 1` in your `webPreferences` object?

Comment: @NilsKähler not working

Comment: Does a resize event fire when moving the window? `window.on('resize', () => {})`

Comment: @NilsKähler Yes, the event is fire. But I dont want to resize it

Comment: Well, you can see what the event contains, if it has a resize parameter attached, what is the new size, perhaps this can shed some light on what the problem is.

Comment: @NilsKähler I get this

 sender: BrowserWindow {
    setBounds: [Function (anonymous)],
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      blur: [Function (anonymous)],
      focus: [Function (anonymous)],
      show: [Function: visibilityChanged],
      hide: [Function: visibilityChanged],
      minimize: [Function: visibilityChanged],
      maximize: [Function: visibilityChanged],
      restore: [Function: visibilityChanged],
      resize: [Function (anonymous)],
      closed: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    _eventsCount: 9,
    devToolsWebContents: [Getter]
  }